# Is a table-valued function updatable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm a bit confused on the update statement but here's what I have: I have these two employees and their respective alpha numeric codes.

```
select * from cm.bo.hotlist('08Z')
where State = 'ca'

select * from cm.bo.hotlist('06D')
where State = 'ca'
```

The table has certain cities associated with each employee, the top select statement has these list of cities associated with '08Z'... let's say.

```
New York
Chicago
```

I would like to move those cities to the employee '06D'

How would I got about updating?

The confusing part for me is the table is a table-valued function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

maybe something like so:

```
update CITY cm.bo.hotlist('06D')

where CITY in (New York, Chicago)
```

Comment: YOu need to look at a the table_valued finction to find the underlying table and then write an update for that. You cannot update a table-valued function. This a permananet dat change though, if you only want to diplay a differnt data temporarily, then, you would do something different.

Comment: Where do people get to thinking you can't update a TVF? It returns a table reference, as long as that reference is updateable it works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what you want is:

```
Update cm.bo.hotlist('08Z')
set
<EmployeeID Column> = '06D'
where
city in ('New York', 'Chicago')
```

---

For everyone who comes here, yes, an in-line table value function is updateable as long as the underlying data set is updateable. A code sample:

```
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.objects where name = 'test' and schema_id = schema_id('dbo')) BEGIN DROP TABLE dbo.test; END

CREATE TABLE dbo.test(Employee varchar(10), city varchar(10));

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getEmployeeCities] ( @employee varchar(10) RETURNS TABLE  AS
RETURN  (  SELECT * from test where employee = @employee );

insert into dbo.test select 'A', 'Chicago';
insert into dbo.test select 'B', 'New York';

select * from dbo.test;

update dbo.getEmployeeCities('A')
set Employee = 'B'
where city = 'Chicago';

select * from dbo.test;
```

Comment: the field for employee is employee_id, looks like i was fairly close to knowing and thanks for the response, i'll give it a go. Is there anything else i should know?

Answer (score 0):

Update Tablename 
SET employes ='06D'
where CITY IN ('NEW York', 'Chicago')