# Insert/Delete operations in Entity Framework C# using a table-valued function

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, user-defined-functions

I'm using Entity Framework 6.  The DBA I'm working with requires that all data operations from the web app I'm working on are done via table-valued functions.

Now, it's possible to perform INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE on a TVF using T-SQL, but again, I'm using EF.  SELECTS and UPDATES on a TVF are easy enough in EF (see [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx), for example).  But **is there a way to use a TVF to do a DELETE or INSERT using a TVF within Entity Framework**?

Here's some sample code that will update the "active" flag on a user record provided by tvfUser.

```
    using (var db = new dbAppUserEntities())
    {
        var user = db.tvfUser(appID).Where(w => w.ID == userID).SingleOrDefault();
        if (user != null)
        {
            user.active = false;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

**How would I delete a user using the same TVF in similar EF-ish fashion?**  How would I create one?  I'm aware that I can simply issue SQL commands through EF (using ExecuteSqlCommand, for instance), but is that my only recourse?

**EDIT:**
In case you're dubious that a TVF can indeed manipulate data at all, I assure you that it can.  Try this if you don't believe me:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_test](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)) 
GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TestFunction]
(   
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT id, value FROM _test 
)
GO

INSERT INTO _test (Value) VALUES ('A','B','C')
GO

SELECT * FROM TestFunction() WHERE id=2 -- Value column = 'B'
UPDATE Testfunction() SET value = 'D' WHERE id=2
SELECT * FROM TestFunction() WHERE id=2 -- now Value column = 'D'
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, when you set user.active = false and call db.SaveChanges EF will run a update query, so your sample code is already doing update not through a tvf. If you want all data operations to be done through TVFs, write different TVFs for each operation and just select from them.

Comment: Very true.  SELECT and UPDATE work fine through the EF model, but I can't find a way to **INSERT or DELETE**, which is my question.

Comment: *Functions* are *functions* not stored procedures. They can' perform data manipulations. In order to perform insert/update/delete you'll have to create stored procedures. These *can* be mapped directly to entities so you don't need any extra calls to use them

Comment: Also note that *functions* can't be executed by themselves, so you are *already* allowing EF to execute ad-hoc SQL statements. Are you sure the DBA specified *TVFs* instead of stored procedures?

Comment: A table-valued function **can** be used to perform data manipulations in T-SQL.  See, for example, [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568454/is-a-table-valued-function-updatable)

Comment: @plunkg which shows nothing of the kind. The *function* is a `SELECT`. The linked question talks about *updatable* functions, just like there are updateable views. In the case of views, the code doesn't have to do *anything*, just use EF's normal modification operations.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I don't mean to be argumentative, but you CAN manipulate data in the underlying table using a TVF, **even though the function performs a SELECT**.  I realize it's counter-intuitive, but it's true.  Here's [another link](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/greg_low/archive/2011/05/22/update-against-a-table-valued-function-when-declared-inline.aspx) demonstrating it.

Comment: @plunkg you are confusing different things, which prevents you from understanding what's wrong with the question. You asked if you can create a function that performs a DELETE. You can't. The links you provide do *not* use the function to delete. They refere to updateable functions or views, ie functions or view that can be included in a separate DELETE statement. You have to be able to generate such a `DELETE` statement in the first place. EF doesn't provide that.

Comment: You can map an entity to a table or updatable view, and EF will generate the proper SELECT/UPDATE etc at runtime. You can map the Select/Insert/Update/Delete operations to separate stored procedures with  [MapToStoredProcedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn468673.aspx) and EF will use the stored procedure instead of generating the statements. You could even do a DELETE in the Select sproc. Mapping operations to functions though isn't provided out-of-the-box. Perhaps an extension can add such mapping, but this is an unusual request